# Nested Soy templates

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

When I try to **call** a Soy template inside another Soy template I get `Uncaught (in promise) Error: No template with namespace TestTemplate.incrementaldom has been loaded yet.` in **chrome console**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the template but not the es file. This is resolved now.